# Writing two column csv file into two seperate lists

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a csv file that has two columns in it: one for names and the other for emails. I have been looking for a way to take the csv file and read it into two lists, one for each column, to later be processed into a database. Could someone please be of assistance?

If it helps the file is formated like:

```
email,name
email,name
etc. . . .
```

Comment: While the question already has a number of satisfactory answers, I would recommend that in the future, you show what you have tried before asking people to provide code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read the file and convert it to `list`, and then split the line with comma:

csv:

```
email,name
1@gmail.com,joe
2@gmail.com,mike
```

---

```
name,email=[],[]
for i in list(open("ooo.csv")):
    name.append(i.strip('\n').split(',')[1])
    email.append(i.strip('\n').split(',')[0])
```

Also you can use `csv.DictReader()`:

e.g.

```
from csv import DictReader

name,email=[],[]
with open("ooo.csv") as f:
    for row in  DictReader(f):
        name.append(row["name"])
        email.append(row["email"])
```

Result:

```
['joe', 'mike']
['1@gmail.com', '2@gmail.com']
```

Or `pandas.read_csv()` method

```
import pandas
colnames = ['name', 'email']
data = pandas.read_csv('ooo.csv', names=colnames)

print(data.name.tolist())
print(data.email.tolist())
```

Output:

```
['email', '1@gmail.com', '2@gmail.com']
['name', 'joe', 'mike']
```

Comment: I ended up using DictReader and it worked out wonderfully for what I'm doing. Thank you very much for the help McGrady.

Answer (score 1):

file:

```
a,b
a,b
a,b
```

A [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) object will produce `['a', 'b']` for each line/row of the file. You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose the result:

```
import csv
with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    email, name = zip(*reader)
```

---

```
>>> email
('a', 'a', 'a')
>>> name
('b', 'b', 'b')
>>>
```

---

You need to ensure that you have as many names on the left hand side of the assignment as there are columns in the csv file - or you could use [extended unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to handle excess columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
email_list = []
name_list = []
with open("the_file") as f:
    for line in f:
        e, n = line.split(',')
        email_list.append(e)
        name_list.append(n)
```